# Applying your own dataset to Keras

Tags: python, keras

I want to play around with training neural networks with genetic algorithms. I have found some code online that utilizes Keras and the data sets in Keras to optimize nerual networks with GAs however I am having the hardest time figuring out how to load and configure my own data set to use with Keras. Here is the code that can calls the MNIST dataset:

```
    def get_mnist():
        """Retrieve the MNIST dataset and process the data."""
        # Set defaults.
        nb_classes = 10
        batch_size = 128
        input_shape = (784,)

        # Get the data.
        (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
        x_train = x_train.reshape(60000, 784)
        x_test = x_test.reshape(10000, 784)
        x_train = x_train.astype('float32')
        x_test = x_test.astype('float32')
        x_train /= 255
        x_test /= 255

        # convert class vectors to binary class matrices
        y_train = to_categorical(y_train, nb_classes)
        y_test = to_categorical(y_test, nb_classes)

        return (nb_classes, batch_size, input_shape, x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test)
```

I have pulled a data set from Kaggle (the flower image prediction set) which I am trying to use. I am trying to load the data set in a way where I can create a function similar to the function. I code I have for loading in my data set is:

```
#%%
# import packages needed for neural network
import numpy as np #shows images
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt #array operations
import os #iterate through directories and move through paths
import cv2 #image operations

#%%
# creates directory and categories
DATADIR = 'pathtodata'
CATEGORIES = ['daisy', 'dandelion', 'rose', 'sunflower', 'tulip']

# iterates through all images in directory
for category in CATEGORIES:
    path = os.path.join(DATADIR, category)
    for img in os.listdir(path):
        # converts image to array and greyscale
        img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,img), cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
        plt.imshow(img_array, cmap="gray")
        plt.show() #one image should print
        break
    break

print(img_array) #print array to check img_array
print(img_array.shape)

# reshape images
IMG_SIZE = 100 #pixel size
new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
plt.imshow(new_array, cmap = 'gray')
plt.show()

# training data
training_data = []
def create_training_data():
    # iterates through all images in directory
    for category in CATEGORIES:
        path = os.path.join(DATADIR, category)
        class_num = CATEGORIES.index(category)
        for img in os.listdir(path):
            try:
                # converts image to array and greyscale
                img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,img), cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
                new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
                training_data.append([new_array, class_num])
            except Exception:
                #any images that are broken will not be included
                pass

create_training_data()

# print training length
print(len(training_data))


#%%
# shuffle training data
import random
random.shuffle(training_data)
for sample in training_data[:10]:
    print(sample[1])

#%%
X=[] #feature set
y=[] #labels

for features, label in training_data:
    X.append(features)
    y.append(label)

# shape needed for keras to except image
X = np.array(X).reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1)

# save the data
import pickle
pickle_out = open("fX.pickle", "wb")
pickle.dump(X, pickle_out)
pickle_out.close()

pickle_out = open("fy.pickle", "wb")
pickle.dump(X, pickle_out)
pickle_out.close()
```

I am then creating and calling the function:

```
def get_flower():
    nb_classes = 4
    batch_size = 32
    input_shape = X.shape[1:]

    # Loads in data
    x=pickle.load(open("fX.pickle","rb"))
    y=pickle.load(open("fy.pickle","rb"))
    x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0)
    x_train = x_train.astype('float32')
    x_train /= 255

    # convert class vectors to binary class matrices
    y_train = to_categorical(y_train, 1)
    y_test = to_categorical(y_test, 1)

    return (nb_classes, batch_size, input_shape, x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test)
```

I am getting a bunch of indexing errors. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

The errors I received are as follows:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-ebadce6a7460> in <module>
    103 
    104 if __name__ == '__main__':
--> 105     main()

<ipython-input-15-ebadce6a7460> in main()
    100                  (generations, population))
    101 
--> 102     generate(generations, population, nn_param_choices, dataset)
    103 
    104 if __name__ == '__main__':

<ipython-input-15-ebadce6a7460> in generate(generations, population, nn_param_choices, dataset)
     54 
     55         # Train and get accuracy for networks.
---> 56         train_networks(networks, dataset)
     57 
     58         # Get the average accuracy for this generation.

<ipython-input-15-ebadce6a7460> in train_networks(networks, dataset)
     20     pbar = tqdm(total=len(networks))
     21     for network in networks:
---> 22         network.train(dataset)
     23         pbar.update(1)
     24     pbar.close()

<ipython-input-3-bb87f4a033ec> in train(self, dataset)
     40         """
     41         if self.accuracy == 0.:
---> 42             self.accuracy = train_and_score(self.network, dataset)
     43 
     44     def print_network(self):

<ipython-input-14-f15ae9ed57cd> in train_and_score(network, dataset)
    146     elif dataset == 'flower':
    147         nb_classes, batch_size, input_shape, x_train, \
--> 148             x_test, y_train, y_test = get_flower()
    149 
    150     model = compile_model(network, nb_classes, input_shape)

<ipython-input-14-f15ae9ed57cd> in get_flower()
     90 
     91     # convert class vectors to binary class matrices
---> 92     y_train = to_categorical(y_train, 1)
     93     y_test = to_categorical(y_test, 1)
     94 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/utils/np_utils.py in to_categorical(y, num_classes)
     27     n = y.shape[0]
     28     categorical = np.zeros((n, num_classes))
---> 29     categorical[np.arange(n), y] = 1
     30     output_shape = input_shape + (num_classes,)
     31     categorical = np.reshape(categorical, output_shape)

IndexError: index 9 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 1
```

Comment: Please add the errors in your question.

Comment: Oh shoots, errors added.